# How to escape the "@" in play framework templates?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, twirl

How to escape the @ in play framework templates (view and tags)? If you add a "@" in any view in play framework it will be automatically processed by the template processor. Even if is an email address or a twitter account.

Answer (score 34):

Just repeat the **@** for example as **@@**: MyTestView.scala.html

```
@()
<html>
   <body>
      Follow me at @@myTwitter
   </body>
</html>
```

The information can be found at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates