# Play framework, Display special characters

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

Hell, I am new to play framework and Scala. I don't know how to display special characters like @, -, "" as text. 
Help!

Comment: In what situation are you displaying these characters?

Comment: For example, when I want to display email address such as example@gmail.com, Scala assumes that @gmail.com is a variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape the "@" in play framework templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077132/how-to-escape-the-in-play-framework-templates)

Comment: Not only is this one of the first things to come up in a search on StackOverflow, but it's also clearly stated in the docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplates

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you are asking how to escape special characters in scala. It's pretty much same as other languages. using escape character \

```
val str = " \\\" "     //output str: \"
```

or follow the below special syntax to store in string value with exactly what is inside the triple quotes.

```
val str = """ \" """   //output str: \"
```